# Fastest way to check if a list contains zero

Tags: performance, wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-7

While preparing an answer to [Secret Santa - Generating 'valid' permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8609644/618728) I came across the need to check if a list contains zero.  I am wondering what the fastest way to do this in ***Mathematica* 7** is, with emphasis on a short list of non-negative integers.

Using `Min[list] === 0` is the fastest I have found, faster than `MemberQ` or `FreeQ`, but I am hoping there is a faster way, on par with the `BitXor` operation below:

```
r = Range@9;
p = Permutations@r;

BitXor[r, #] & /@ p; // Timing
0 === Min[BitXor[r, #]] & /@ p; // Timing
```

```
{0.062, Null}
```

```
{0.452, Null}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that part of the slowdown with `0 === Min` as used in the question is interference with the autocompile of `Map`.  Separating these steps provides nearly a twofold improvement:

```
r = Range@9;
p = Permutations@r;

Min@# === 0 & /@ (BitXor[r, #] & /@ p); // Timing
```

```
{0.296, Null}
```

---

If I accept a result as (0|1) and if I process the list as one then I can use this:

```
Unitize[Times @@ BitXor[r, #] & /@ p]; // Timing
```

```
{0.156, Null}
```